# Can't find android studio template directory

Tags: android, android-studio

i always use custom template on my own work to write less code
but on new version **Android Studio 4.1** i can't find this directory ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found a god way to automate my code  and make custom template and modules
just by make a new android studio plugin
thank for **Marcos Holgado** for his topics and articles

you could find examples here

https://github.com/marcosholgado/plugin-app

and could learn more from this track

https://caster.io/courses/building-a-plugin-for-android-studio